# Two side-by-side divs within div, but one div is lower than the other

Tags: html, css

I have two smaller divs within a larger div: one is on the left side and one is on the right. However, the two divs are not vertically aligned as seen in the link below.

[divs as seen on webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOo8W.png)

I've seen many solutions saying to use `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:top` but nothing seems to work for me.

HTML and CSS code:

```css
.first-two {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
.curr-val {
  float:right;
  width:50%;
}
.neigh {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-two">
  <div class="neigh">
    <h4><b>Select your neighbourhood</b></h4>
    <div class="custom-select">
     <select id="location" class="dropdown">
      ...
     </select>
    </div>
   </div>
       <br />
      
   <div class="curr-val">
    <h4><b>What's the current value of your house?</b></h4>
    <h4 id="current_value_text" style="color:#333">$200,000</h4>
    <div class="slider-box">
   <input type="range" id="value_slider" min="200000" max="1000000" value="200000" step="50000" onchange="update_slider_current(this.value)">
   </div>
   <br />
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: delete the br between both element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `br` between the two `div`s:

```css
.first-two {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
.curr-val {
  float:right;
  width:50%;
}
.neigh {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-two">
  <div class="neigh">
    <h4><b>Select your neighbourhood</b></h4>
    <div class="custom-select">
      <select id="location" class="dropdown">
        ...
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
          
  <div class="curr-val">
    <h4><b>What's the current value of your house?</b></h4>
    <h4 id="current_value_text" style="color:#333">$200,000</h4>
    <div class="slider-box">
    <input type="range" id="value_slider" min="200000" max="1000000" value="200000" step="50000" onchange="update_slider_current(this.value)">
    </div>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was just a careless mistake that I didn't notice